# How do I setup CKEditor to work with MVC 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ckeditor

I can't seem to find a step by step tutorial of how to get this up and running.  Any help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's one](http://www.arief.me/post/2010/07/20/Integrating-CKEditor-in-ASPNET-MVC-2.aspx).

Comment: Darin looking ont the link and i can not access it, could you post it again? thnx